# Rails options_from_collection_for_select return unique year values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using this to get a select with all dates:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(ObjectModel.all, :id, :get_year)
```

And this is my get_year method from model:

```
def get_year
  date_attr.strftime("%Y")
end
```

But it will return this:

2015

2015

2015

However, I need this years to be unique.

How Can I do this?

Comment: But if few records have the same year then which ID should be taken ?

Comment: I only need this to filter by year, so I think the id is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no matter which ID from records with the same year attribute must be taken then you can do it this way:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(ObjectModel.all.to_a.uniq{ |o| o.get_year}, :id, :get_year)
```

But the better way is to replace this part

```
ObjectModel.all.to_a.uniq{ |o| o.get_year}
```

with scope that retrieves unique (by year) records on DB level. This will depend on your DB.

You may also have to sort the records. Then:

```
ObjectModel.order(:date_attr).uniq{ |o| o.get_year}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where this get_year come from?

Comment: This is your get_year method from model.